# Keyboard shortcut tags are messy

Tags: discussion, tags

#### Completed:

- [keyboard-shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) which is weird, as we symlinked keyboard-shortcut to shortcut-keys a while back. This one not only is dupe but ended up with a tag wiki, woo!
- [key-bindings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/key-bindings)
- [keybindings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keybindings)
- [keyboard-accelerators](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-accelerators)

Our master tag seems to be:
[shortcut-keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shortcut-keys)

#### Incomplete/not sure about:

- [keycodes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keycodes)
- [keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keys)
- [key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/key) seems to be a mix of ssh/gpg, and keybinding stuff, I am not sure if I should just go in there and sort them or let a moderator do it so it doesn't clobber the homepage.

Comment: I'll sort through this this afternoon. As for key(s), we can't ninja edit, so just go for it if you have time.

Comment: I've fixed `key` but I am not sure if we want to blacklist it so it doesn't end up returning, as it could be ssh keys, gpg keys, keyboard keys, etc.

Comment: Blacklisting is something that needs to be discussed in its own question since we have to go to the SE team for that.

Comment: Yeah maybe we should leave it, if in a few months that one is a mess again then we can bother.